# Is it a mistake to show edges of an undirected graph as an ordered pair?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usT0P.jpg) below where it says (i,j) \epsilon E

Pg 49 of the following [pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/409-winter-2014/DisOpt409-Winter2014.pdf) will show you this equation

```
Question 1:
```

Is (i,j) an ordered pair given its with **parentheses** and not **curly braces**

```
Question 2:
```

Page 5 of the same pdf describes an edge with **curly braces** implying an edge is a set and an edge set is a set of sets. Any thoughts here ?

Answer (score 0):

Page 43 of the [pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/409-winter-2014/DisOpt409-Winter2014.pdf) describes network as a directed graph. I feel silly asking it but I answered it here.